# Могу ли я изменить поле Издатель на странице своего приложения в Google Play Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Хочу зарегистрироваться как разработчик физ.лицо в Google Play, чтобы публиковать бесплатные приложения для Android. После регистрации я смогу установить в Маркете для своего приложения поле Издатель(Разработчик) в название своего сайта, а не ФИО?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Вы можете такое сделать. Фото с настроек профиля
[image: Да. Вы можможете такое сделать]

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Console -> Настройки -> Аккаунт Разработчика -> Сведения об аккаунте.

Имя разработчика*